# Are games on topic?

Tags: discussion, site-scope

There's already a gaming SE, and superuser, which is much like this site, explicitly excludes games.

Answer (score 3):

I'd ask the game related questions on Gaming as games are the sole topic of that site.
I'd expect this site to be about fixing problems you have with any Apple device.

Furthermore, most games are or will be cross-platform (like with Steam on OSX), so you're more likely to get an answer on Gaming.

However, if you have a problem installing or running certain games, then it's more a platform problem and you're better off asking it here.

If this turns out to be a frequent problem, I assume you guys will get a migration path towards Gaming in the foreseeable future (post-beta)